# How To Create a iPhoto Like Interface

Tags: cocoa

I'm trying to create a iPhoto like application, where using an array of objects I want to display a thumb along with a title at the bottom of each thumb. How do I display objects like iPhoto does?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at [NSCollectionView / NSCollectionViewItem](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CollectionViews/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009030).

There is another tool palette in Interface Builder called [Image Kit](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/ImageKitProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html). You have to enable the plugin in IB's preferences (the Plug-ins palette). Then, under the object library, select the Image Kit to see the controls it offers. IKImageBrowserView gives you a ready-made control (with the ability to show titles) but I don't think it's as flexible as NSCollectionView/Item.

Comment: I think your answer is enough for me. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. I went ahead and added the information for Image Kit, to which I was referring earlier.