# how to display pictures as thumbnails in a view

Tags: cocoa

I am trying to get a view with multiple pictures as thumbnails; but i am not really savy about how to obtain this.

can anyone tell me how can i create a thumbnail view from files in a folder and show it like in a tableview (or whatever is the name of the container).

I wanna show all the pictures thou, not just one, so i cannot use just an imageview control.

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How To Create a iPhoto Like Interface](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3270911/how-to-create-a-iphoto-like-interface)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was asked and answered recently here: [How To Create a iPhoto Like Interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3270911/how-to-create-a-iphoto-like-interface)